# NodeJS + Express + MongoDB using Mongoose Sequence not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

a tryng to create a collection using auto increment number in the _id data, but stay "Sending request" and I not have callback in this call. I really dont know what I cant making work

> ```
> "mongoose": "^7.5.3"
> "mongoose-sequence": "^5.3.1"
> "node": "v20.8.0"
> ```

*domain.model.js*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const AutoIncrement = require("mongoose-sequence")(mongoose);

const schema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: {
      type: Number,
    },

    domain: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
  }
);
schema.plugin(AutoIncrement, { inc_field: "_id" });
const domain = mongoose.model("domain", schema);

module.exports = domain;
```

*my function*

```
const isSetSearchDomain = async (dom) => {
  try {
    let promise = new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      const domainPromises = dom.map(async (domain) => {
        let existingDomain = await Domain.findOne({ domain: domain });

        if (!existingDomain) {
          const newDomain = await new Domain({
            domain: domain
          });

          await newDomain
            .save()
            .then((documento) => {
              console.log("Documento salvo com sucesso:", documento);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error(err);
            });

          await newDomain.setNext("_id", function (err, dom) {
            console.log(dom._id);
          });

          console.log(newDomain);

          return {
            _id: newDomain._id,
            domain: domain,
          };
        } else {
          return {
            _id: existingDomain._id,
            domain: domain,
          };
        }
      });

      const results = await Promise.all(domainPromises);
      resolve(results);
    });

    return promise.then((p) => p);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    log.error(error);
    return false;
  }
};
```

When I put `await` in `await newDomain.save()` still loading request

It keeps loading an API request and doesn't return anything, I really don't know what the error would be exactly, I've tried everything to make a collection using incremental id

Answer (score 1):

Remove _id from Schema as You don't need to define the id field in your schema because the plugin automatically sets it for you. The only thing you have to do is to call.

Comment: Also, you dont need await in 
const newDomain = await new Domain({
            domain: domain
          });